# How to have a bool go to true or false, based on a float increasing or decreasing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I Have 2 Boolean's "FacingRight" and "FacingLeft" they aren't working as I would like and I thought of a better idea but have absolutely no idea on how to go about doing it.

I want to make FacingRight = true and FacingLeft = false if the X position value of the gameobject(player) has increased, which means it moved right, FacingRight = false and FacingLeft = true when the X value has decreased.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my current code if that helps.

```
public float fireAnimDelay;
Animator anim;

public bool FacingRight = false;
public bool FacingLeft = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    anim.GetFloat("Speed");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (anim.GetFloat("Speed") >= 0.1f) // If speed is positive you are facing right
    {
        FacingRight = true;
        Debug.Log("FacingRight");
    }

    if (anim.GetFloat("Speed") <= -0.1f) // if speed is negative you are facing left
    {
        FacingLeft = true;
    }

    if (anim.GetFloat("Speed") == 0.0f) // if speed is 0 you are idle
    {
        FacingRight = false;
        FacingLeft = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z) && FacingRight == true)
    {
        FacingLeft = false;

        anim.SetBool("Firing", true);
        anim.SetBool("FacingRight", true);
        anim.SetBool("FacingLeft", false);
        StartCoroutine(FireDelay());
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z) && FacingLeft == true)
    {
        FacingRight = true;

        anim.SetBool("Firing", true);
        anim.SetBool("FacingLeft", true);
        anim.SetBool("FacingRight", false);
        StartCoroutine(FireDelay());
    }
}

IEnumerator FireDelay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(fireAnimDelay);
    anim.SetBool("Firing", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to achieve this is to make use of one or more events. Although you can also achieve this using other techniques, event-base programming gives you priceless advantages of which the simplest one is to allow you to run different task when your value has changes in different context. (you can read more on events through Google)

The following code provides an example of how you can apply something similar in your code:

```
public class FloatIncreasing
{
    private float _Value;
    public float Value {
        get {
            return _Value;
        }
        set {
            ValueChangeEvent(this, _Value >= value);
            _Value = value;
        }
    }
    public Boolean HasIncreased { get; private set; }
    public event EventHandler<Boolean> ValueChangeEvent;
    public FloatIncreasing() {
        this.ValueChangeEvent += OnValueChanged; 
    }
    public virtual void OnValueChanged(Object sender, Boolean value) {
        HasIncreased = value;
        // You can add a more appropriate default behavior in here. 
    }
}
```

Considering this code, you can consume it the following way:

```
class Program
{
    static FloatIncreasing test = new FloatIncreasing();
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        test.ValueChangeEvent += Test_ValueChangeEvent;
        test.Value = 0;
        test.Value = 10;
        test.Value = 3;
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    private static void Test_ValueChangeEvent(object sender, bool e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e ? "Value Decreased or Not Changed" : "Value increased");
    }
}
```

Please note that anytime the `test.Value` is changed, the corresponding event is triggered allowing you to modify your boolean value.

Comment: I'm pretty new to C# and Unity so there's a lot of stuff here I'm not getting, if anyone could further break this down for me that would be awesome.

Comment: I'll also be researching in the meantime and hopefully get this working

Comment: @OmBiEaTeR In simplest words, what you need is an event. `An event in C# is a way for a class to provide notifications to clients of that class when some interesting thing (change) happens to an object`

Comment: I'm only getting one error with this script and I'm not sure what it means, could anyone explain to me what it means.

Comment: The type `bool' cannot be used as type parameter `TEventArgs' in the generic type or method `System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>'. There is no boxing conversion from `bool' to `System.EventArgs'

Comment: @OmBiEaTeR: change `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` to `EventHandler<Boolean>` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error in your code:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z) && FacingRight == true) {
    FacingLeft = false;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z) && FacingLeft == true) {
    FacingRight = true;
}
```

Notice how in the one instance you set Left to false if facing right, but in the complimentary block you *set Right to true!*

Also, `anim.GetFloat("Speed") >= 0.1f` You should check `<` or `>` than 0, otherwise values between 0 and 0.1 aren't going to be detected (or use if...elseif...else).

A better approach would be to reduce the FacingLeft/Right variable to a single variable:

```
enum Facing { NONE, LEFT, RIGHT }
Facing playerFacing = Facing.NONE;

//...

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z) && playerFacing == Facing.RIGHT) {
    //...
}
```

As well as using `Input.GetButton("Fire")` instead of hard-coded key codes.  This will allow your players to rebind the keys (maybe they don't like your WASD movement setup and prefer [HJKL](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/why-vim-uses-hjkl-as-arrow-keys/)).